# How to connect a Facebook app to my own MYSQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook

I'm new at making Facebook apps and this is my first time doing one so please bear with me. :)

I already made a Facebook app and I "sortof tried" to connect it to a localhost database on MYSQL but failed.

I have two questions at the moment: 
1) is there a way to connect my facebook app to my own database and how?

2) since the facebook app I made only has one page at the moment, I don't know how to connect it to a new one. how can I connect the app's page to another page?

Oh, and I'm using the heroku thing that Facebook provided. the free web hosting thing, I think. and I'm using PHP SDK. My prefered language is PHP since I'm using dreamweaver to create this whole thing.

Comment: That's a lot to answer in one question. Have you given any thought to using a framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [CodeIgnighter](http://codeigniter.com/)? Those can give you some structure when getting started.

Comment: @tadman: unfortunately, i can only use heroku.

Comment: Both those frameworks are just PHP and should work anywhere that supports that kind of hosting.

Comment: yes they do but i don't know how to create a database and create tables using heroku's postgres. And i can't seem to also connect it.

Comment: Both of those should have a guide on how to set up on Postgres. That would be a lot easier than building from a blank slate.

Comment: that's kind of my problem too. i can only use Heroku. and Heroku has a specific Postgres add-on.  my problem now is that i have created a database there already but i can't seem to create tables on it. do i still need to download and install the Postgres on my machine? coz since Heroku and Postgres is cloud-based so i guess that has me confused.

Comment: Usually people do development on their local machine and deploy to Heroku. I'm not sure that live-coding on Heroku is the best idea.